# Difference between setcookie() and session_set_cookie_params() functions

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am trying to understand the difference between PHP functions setcookie() and session_set_cookie_params().

Looks like both functions are doing the same kind of tasks but setcookie() can be used to create cookie with name & value.

I tried to understand PHP manuals but no clear differences pointed out in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

session_set_cookie_params(seconds)

session_start() does two things, it creates a temporary file on the server of which to store session data, and also sends a cookie to the user's browser. This cookie has a default expiration time, so calling session_set_cookie_params(seconds) will change the default expiration time of the cookie to what you define. The cookie basically points the client to their session so it is required to access the session.

Set Cookie()

where as setcookie() function defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 7):

There are two types of cookies:

**Session cookies :** these are the session_set_cookie_params() and these are temporary cookie files, which are erased when you close your browser.

**Persistent cookies :** this is the setcookie() and these files stay in one of your browser's subfolders until you delete them manually or your browser deletes them based on the duration period contained within the persistent cookies.

For example if you want to have cookies to be saved for 1 week:

```
$remembering_timespan = time() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60; 
setcookie('test','username', $remembering_timespan);
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically it's not the same.

For `setcookie`

```
<?php
$value = 'something from somewhere';

setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/~rasmus/", "example.com", 1);
?>
```

You could set like the above, the timeout session with the name and value itself.
As for session_set_cookie_params:

```
session_set_cookie_params( 
    $currentCookieParams["lifetime"], 
    $currentCookieParams["path"], 
    $rootDomain, 
    $currentCookieParams["secure"], 
    $currentCookieParams["httponly"] 
);
```

You can set the path , expiry of the cookie itself, the root domain , the secure level and many more parameter at here `http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php`

The efficient way via PHP is below:

```
<?php 
$currentCookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); 

$rootDomain = '.example.com'; 

session_set_cookie_params( 
    $currentCookieParams["lifetime"], 
    $currentCookieParams["path"], 
    $rootDomain, 
    $currentCookieParams["secure"], 
    $currentCookieParams["httponly"] 
); 

session_name('mysessionname'); 
session_start(); 

setcookie($cookieName, $cookieValue, time() + 3600, '/', $rootDomain); 
?>
```

The efficient coder ensure the parameter are to be set before setting the parameter itself so if the user is off grid. There's expiry on the cookie itself.

Comment: A more efficient way to handle sessions is to set the lifetime to 0.  That makes it a session cookie, which will be deleted once the user closes their browser.  This also means that you don't need to do the setcookie() every time the user interacts with your application.

Answer (score 0):

With `session_set_cookie_params()` you can define the cookie options (like lifetime, etc.). If a session gets started these values are used for the cookie that is sent to the client. The cookie however is sent only at the beginning of the session but not for any further requests from the client. This means that the cookie with be removed by the client after `[session start time] + [timeout]` has been reached. Effectively you define a max lifetime of a session.

Whereas `setcookie()` actually resends the cookie not matter if it is a new session or an existing one. This means that the cookie well be renewed by every request the client will only remove it after `[time of last request] + [timeout]` has been reached. Effectively you define a max time of inactivity of a session.

Answer (score -1):

**setcookie()** defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output, including  and  tags as well as any whitespace.

for **setcookie()** to be working, you need to call **session_set_cookie_params()** for every request and before **session_start()** and others like **setcookie()** are called.

Comment: Looks like session_set_cookie_params() is meant for server side and setcookie() for client side.?

Comment: session_set_cookie_params()  means select the parameters that we use to set cookie it may be our username, or something else

Comment: set cookie is used when there is parameter to be used

Answer (score -2):

I thinks, maybe difference between setcookie() and session_set_cookie_params() functions is turn domain.com and sub.domain.com.