# PHP: New cookie on refresh?

Tags: php, cookies, refresh, session-cookies

How do I generate a new cookie every time the page is refreshed?

I'm new and learning about secure session cookies. I'm supposed to print the session id/cookie value on a start page and on connected pages. At the moment the value is printed on all pages but I would like it to change on every refresh of the start page.

Parts of my code below (excluding the html file and other pages where the value is printed).

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
$session_id = session_id();

$expires = time() + 10800; 
$path = "/"; 
$domain = "domain";
$secure = true;
$httponly = true;

setcookie("session-id-secure", $session_id, $expires, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);

//Read HTML-file
$file = fopen("securecookie.html","r");
$html = fread($file,filesize("securecookie.html"));
fclose($file);

//Replace markers in HTML with cookie value/session id
$html_id = "---session-id-secure---";
$newhtml = str_replace($html_id, $_COOKIE["session-id-secure"], $html);
echo $newhtml;
```

Comment: Setting httpOnly and secure flag to true should do the trick. Token refresh isn't a full proof thing but rather avoiding the attacker to replay the same token multiple times. If the attacker replays the token first than the actual user, it's denial of service for the actual user and proper response for the attacker.

Comment: Thank you, maybe I misunderstood but I thought I had already set httpOnly and secure to true? And it's still not working, unfortunately..

Comment: Not working as in the flags aren't set?

Comment: I meant not working as in the cookie still has the same value after every refresh. I think the flags should be set, I checked in "Advanced REST Client" for Chrome where it says that set-cookie has "secure" and "HttpOnly"

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue at my end as I see new session ID every time.

Comment: Also, the `$secure = true;` will work when you go live and have https enabled for your site. It won't for localhost but never tried with self signed SSL for local environment.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for looking into it, appreciate your help! I'm using my university's file server which has https enabled. So I can see the value but it doesn't change on refresh of the start page. In the other pages (linked from start page) I'm just echoing the $_COOKIE["session-id-secure"] and it shows the same value.

Comment: I tested this on a browser. Are you checking on the ftp tool by any chance? This would work on a browser as browser sends back the cookies to the server for further manipulation.

Comment: I'm testing it in Google Chrome

Comment: Is the protocol `http` or anything else as I can't reproduce it at my end?

Comment: Looks like https

Comment: Then it's pretty unlikely. BTW, I checked cookie values in the application tab upon opening inspect element.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. Seems like it's working, even though I can't see it, haha.

Comment: I have another question, is there any difference in using `session_set_cookie_params(time()+10800);` or setting the cookie like above?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385444/difference-between-setcookie-and-session-set-cookie-params-functions